# Question operation on indicator function [uniform distribution]

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I do not understand a particular step in deriving the likelihood function for a continuous uniform distribution $U[0,\theta]$. This has to do with a particular operation on the indicator function.

[image: In this link you can find the steps which have to be performed]

My problem arises in Step 4. What is the rationale in this step? What is the performed operation and why is it allowed? My tutorial teacher said the inverse is taken of all terms but how do we in that case come up with the interval $[0,1]$. She said to use 1/0 = $\infty$ but if I recall correctly this is not true (division by zero is undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed because if $y>0, \theta>0$ then 
$\frac{\theta}{y_{(n)}}\geq1\Rightarrow \theta\geq y_{(n)}\Rightarrow 1\geq\frac{y_{(n)}}{\theta}>0$

So
$I_{[1,\infty]}\bigg(\frac{\theta}{y_{(n)}}\bigg)=I_{(0,1]}\bigg(\frac{y_{(n)}}{\theta}\bigg)$
or
$I_{[1,\infty]}\bigg(\frac{\theta}{y_{(n)}}\bigg)=I_{[0,1]}\bigg(\frac{y_{(n)}}{\theta}\bigg)$ a.e. (almost everywhere).

Comment: Intuitively very clear.

Answer (score -1):

Because for positive $n$, if $n< x\leqslant 1$ then $1\leqslant x^{-1}<n^{-1}$ so therefore taking the limits:
$$\lim_{n\to 0^+}\mathbf I_{[n;1]}(x)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbf I_{[1;m]}(x^{-1})\qquad (m=n^{-1})$$

Which we can abbreviate as: $$\mathbf I_{[0;1]}(x)=\mathbf I_{[1;\infty)}(x^{-1})$$

That is all.

Comment: Actually, that is not all, one should one way or another use the fact that $P(y_{(n)}=0)=0$.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your line of reasoning entirely. Why do you take x > n?

Comment: And you take two different limits on both sides of the equal size? That is allowed? And why do you have [1,n] instead of [1,n^-1] in the second limit?

Comment: Change of bound variable.

Comment: What does ''change of bound variable'' mean exactly? Intuitively, I would say that n > x.